# Swapping hosting, website and domain over?

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting

I need to swap web hosting and domain over. I am better at coding than hosting so please forgive my beginner knowledge.

Currently I have created a website on my own personal Domain Name ie. www.123.com, on Wordpress with Blue Host hosting. My old website is produced on Dreamweaver, with Fasthosts hosting and a different domain ie. www.abc.com.

Does anyone know how I go about removing the old dreamweaver website on FastHosts and set up with my new Wordpress website BUT keeping the Fasthosts domain name?!

Or is this all an FTP job?

Comment: This might help you: http://madebydenis.com/manually-migrate-locally-developed-wordpress-site-to-a-live-server/ Plus this isn't a programming question per se. So try [server fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: P.S. Hopefully you mean SFTP instead of FTP? If not - please try to move over

Answer (score 0):

You should login to your fasthost FTP. From there delete the old website files, then download your wordpress files from bluehost and upload them to the fasthost domain with ftp. Keep in mind that when you move your website you also need to move your database and change your wp-config file. For more info about this see: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress